# LINUX MINT CINNAMON 17.3 (2.8.8) No kTinker GUI when trying to execute outside of IDLE3

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and about 20hrs into Ktinker, but I assume my problem is beloved Linux.

I created a module, I've done the shebang and chmod +x Water_Ratio.py
. I've also right clicked the file and properties/permissions/ and made sure there's a X in Executable checkbox.
I've checked environment:>> echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games::        I gather /usr/bin has to be there   -  it is.

I saved the file to usb and booted windows, and unfortunately, Windows runs it. It opens a CMD and then opens my gui.

I can open other .py files by dragging to Terminal or selecting Run in Terminal" and they do work, its pretty obvious its a Linux issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
BTW the program is intended to assist me in doing water changes on a fishtank and getting the temperature correct. Feel free to use it if you have similar interests.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import time
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Water Ratio calculator")
window.geometry("350x200")
#--- functions
def calc_out():
    volume =int(entry_vol.get())
    tankTemp =int(entry_tt.get())
    coldTemp =int(entry_ct.get())

    #calculation
    hot_supply_temp=100
    hot_required=volume/(((tankTemp-coldTemp)/(hot_supply_temp-tankTemp)*7)+7)*((tankTemp-coldTemp)/(hot_supply_temp-tankTemp)*7)
    cold_required=volume/(((tankTemp-coldTemp)/(hot_supply_temp-tankTemp)*7)+7)*7

    #cold_output1
    cold_label=tk.Label(text="Cold required")
    cold_label.grid(column=0,row=5,sticky="w")
    coldisplay=tk.Text(master=window,height=1,width=5)
    coldisplay.grid(column=0,row=5,sticky="e")
    coldisplay.insert(tk.END,cold_required)

    #hot_output1
    hot_label=tk.Label(text="Hot required")
    hot_label.grid(column=0,row=6,sticky="w")
    hotout=tk.Text(master=window,height=1,width=5)
    hotout.grid(column=0,row=6,sticky="e")
    hotout.insert(tk.END,hot_required)
    #end of function


#label
title = tk.Label(text="My Water Calculator App",font=("Times New Roman",20))
title.grid(column=0,row=0)

#volume
volume = tk.Label(text="How much are you changing",)
volume.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="w")

    #entry field
entry_vol=tk.Entry(width=5)
entry_vol.grid(column=1,row=1)


#tank temp
tanktemp = tk.Label(text="What is the tank temperature?")
tanktemp.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="w")


    #entry field
entry_tt=tk.Entry(width=5)
entry_tt.grid(column=1,row=2)

#cold temp
coldtemp = tk.Label(text="What is the Cold water temperature?")
coldtemp.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="w")

    #entry field
entry_ct=tk.Entry(width=5)
entry_ct.grid(column=1,row=3)


#button
run=tk.Button(text="Run",bg="blue",command=calc_out )

run.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky="w")

window.mainloop()
```

[linux properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3voG.png)[linux vers[in idle3[working in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jBoP.jpg)

Comment: linux ls -l = -rwxr-xr-x 1 craig craig   1855 Aug  6 21:52 Water_Ratio.py

Answer (score 0):

i've sorted it. The file always remains "un-double-clickable" but I created a desktop launcher to it and it ran like a charm.[Desktop_Launcher1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTFck.png)

[Desktop_Launcher2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8KZv.png)